# Magento 1.9 - Add a tax free product to a specific product when adding to the shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, tax

When I add a specific product to the shopping cart, I want also automatically add a tax-free product to the shopping cart.

### Example

- Adding a watch(€500) with 21% tax to the shopping cart
- Automatically add the taxless product (€30)

So the price will be €500+21% tax (€605) + the €30 taxless fee.
Total price: €635

How can I do this?

Comment: do you also need to sell the taxless product separately with tax applied or will it always be tax-free?

Comment: It must always be tax-free product.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to either write a load of custom code or use an extension

https://www.j2t-design.net/j2t-auto-add-products.html

Using extension above you could set second product as zero discount - so full price. Providing the product itself is taxless class that should work. Magento will handle tax calculation.